# How to turn this CSS with plain javascript or jQuery instead of hover to on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<div class="flip3d">
   <div class="back" >Box1-I</div>
   <div class="front">Box1-Front</div>
</div>

<div class="flip3d">
   <div class="back" >Box2-back</div>
   <div class="front">Box2-Front</div>
</div>

<div class="flip3d">
   <div class="back" >Box3-back</div>
   <div class="front">Box3-Front</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flip3d{
    width:200px;
    height;200px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
 }
.flip3d>.front{
    position:absolute;
    transform:perspective(600px)rotateY(0deg);
    background:#FC0; width:200px; height:200px; border-radius:6px;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    transition: transform 1s linear 0s;
 }
.flip3d>.back{
    position:absolute;
    transform:perspective(600px)rotateY(180deg);
    background:lightgreen; width:200px; height:200px; border-radius:6px;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    transition: transform 1s linear 0s;
}
```

JS

```
 $(function(){
  $('.flip3d').on('click',function(){
  if($(this).children('.front')) {

 $(this).children('.front').css({'transform':'
  perspective(600px)rotateY(-180deg)'});

    if($(this).children('.back')) {

  $(this).children('.back').css
 ({'transform':'perspective(600px)rotateY(0deg)'});
  }
   });
     });
```

what i want to do is to make the div flip the same exact thing but on click instead of hover to be compatible with touch screen  it might be noob question for some of you 
thanks in advance:)

**Edited :**

thanks to @AaronEveleth logic
i have found the solution  with jQuery now when i click it flip to back but when i click again it doesn't go to front again any suggestion why?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more 
research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: You are mistaking [so] for a free coding service. Please show a minimal effort in achieving the task yourself and/or outline any problems you currently have. Your current problem is you haven't started coding.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i have tried couple of things but it didn't work  , i thought this section to ask questions and share answers that all ..i'm new to site as you can see though ..

Comment: @IWantBeBetter not knowing a community's rules doesn't mean you are allowed to break or ignore them. Take your time and read through the links Peter provided above. Welcome to [so].

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu okay sorry i didn't mean to break any rules or offend anyone and thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you currently have the code inside the `:hover` blocks, you can change the block to a different class, something like `click-class`. Here is an example of how you can do that:

```
/* The code you had for on hover */
.flip3d:hover >.front{
  transform:perspective(600px)rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flip3d:hover >.back{
  transform:perspective(600px)rotateY(0deg);
}

/* An example of what you can change it to */
.click-class-front {
  transform:perspective(600px)rotateY(-180deg);
}
.click-class-front {
  transform:perspective(600px)rotateY(0deg);
}
```

Then in your javascript/jquery code, you can do something like this:

```
$('.flip3d').click(function(){
    if($(this).children('.front')) {
        $(this).children('.front').toggleClass('click-class-front');
    }

    if($(this).children('.back')) {
        $(this).children('.back').toggleClass('click-class-back');
    }
});
```

When you click on the div with class `front` or `back`, it will check which one was clicked based on the class that is applied to them. It will then toggle(add or remove depending on previous state) the class, and the code in the CSS with that class will be applied.

**Note to SO Community:** *Not able to comment, so I apologize about my improper use of an answer*

Comment: Aaron, not having enough reputation to comment does not, by any means, mean you can use answers instead. If you decide to answer, provide a proper answer. As of now, it looks like you didn't take the time to study the snippet in question. Toggling the class on click is a good approach, but you should also explain (or demo) how the styles from `:hover` should be moved to the class. You probably want to create a working example, using the snippet tool.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it's bad practice. Luckily the up vote on this answer put be above 50. So I won't be doing that anymore. I appreciate the respectful response. I agree, my answer is lacking proper explanation. I will update with your suggested changes now.

Comment: @AaronEveleth thanks for your effort but it doesn't seem to work with me ; (

Comment: @IWantBeBetter Make sure you've included the jQuery library as well.

Comment: @AaronEveleth i have added it already but i think the problem is i click on the parent div not the back or front,  if it works with you can you provide HTML as well please?

Comment: @IWantBeBetter I have updated click event to fire for the parent element. I suggest looking through my edits to see what I changed.